# Change the appearance of labels with Tkinter events

Tags: python, events, user-interface, tkinter

Context: I'm **okay** at Python, but not yet familiar with all its functionality.

I'm trying to build a GUI using Tkinter, and I'd like to know whether I can have this happen:
If a radio button is selected, then one of the five labels will disappear. If another radio button is pressed, then the hidden label will appear and another label will disappear.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

v = IntVar()
v.set(0)


physVar = (
    ("a", 1),
    ("vi", 2),
    ("vf", 3),
    ("t", 4),
    ("x", 5)
    )


def ShowChoice():
    print physVar[v.get()-1][0]


Label(root, 
    text="Solve for:",
    padx = 5
    ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 6)

for txt, val in physVar:
    Radiobutton(root,
    text= txt,
    variable = v,
    command=ShowChoice,
    value=val).grid(row=1, column = val)


for txt, val in physVar:
    Label(root,
        text=txt).grid(column = 0, row = val+1)

for txt, val in physVar:
    Entry(root,
        text=txt).grid(column = 1, columnspan = 5, row = val +1)
mainloop()
```

What I'd like is, for example, if I clicked on the radio button for "a", then the label "a" and the entry next to it will disappear.

EDIT: I might also include what I'm trying to build: a kinematic equations solving calculator like this one - http://planetcalc.com/981/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already have a function which runs when the `Radiobutton` is changed, so obviously that's where the code needs to go.

To change anything about you widgets, you need to keep a reference to them, and since you're making them in a loop, I'd suggest putting these references in a list. You also need to separate the making of the widget and the `grid` call, since `grid` returns `None`.

What you can then do is use `grid_remove()` to remove a widget from the window, while remembering where they were put. You can then put this `grid_remove` call in the function that runs when the radiobutton is clicked and put the other ones back with just `grid()`. Because you don't know which one was removed the last time, you can just re-grid all the widgets before removing the one that needs to go. I also removed the first `Entry` and `Label` because `Radiobutton a` is automatically selected.

When you type stuff in one of the `Entry` boxes and then select the `Radiobutton` that removes it and then another again, you can actually see the widget is never really destroyed but just removed from the grid, because the text in it is still there.

See this example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

v = IntVar()
v.set(0)

physVar = (("a", 0), ("vi", 1), ("vf", 2), ("t", 3), ("x", 4))

def change_radio():
    for i in range(5):
        e[i].grid()
        l[i].grid()
    e[v.get()].grid_remove()
    l[v.get()].grid_remove()

Label(root, text="Solve for:", padx=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)

r=[]
for txt, val in physVar:
    r.append(Radiobutton(root, text= txt, variable = v, command=change_radio, value=val))
    r[-1].grid(row=1, column=val+1)

l=[]
for txt, val in physVar:
    l.append(Label(root, text=txt))
    l[val].grid(column=0, row=val+2)

e=[]
for txt, val in physVar:
    e.append(Entry(root,text=txt))
    e[val].grid(column=1, columnspan=5, row=val+2)

e[0].grid_remove()
l[0].grid_remove()

root.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=4)
root.mainloop()
```